# Python hex decoder

Tags: python, encoding, hex, ascii, decoding

Hey I need to decode hex and write to text file but I can only encode it not decode.
I've written a script to encode which works and prints into text file called encoded.txt.

```
import binascii
with open('encoded.txt','r') as text:
    a = text.readlines()
    for x in a:
        b = binascii.unhexlify(x)
        with open('decoded.txt','a') as done:
            done.write(b + "\n")
```

So far I encoded (print " Hello World!") which returns 7072696e74202248656c6c6f20576f726c642122 but when i try to decode it it return an error stating that it was oddly length string. Could this be because i used "\n" in the encoder?
Thankyou

Comment: Try `strip`ping the string before decoding it if you think it might be caused by whitespace

Comment: I am trying to decode 7072696e74202248656c6c6f20576f726c642122  to try and get (print "Hello World!")

Comment: @IsithaSubasinghe: if you use `print repr(x)` you'll see that you don't have `'7072696e74202248656c6c6f20576f726c642122'`, but `'7072696e74202248656c6c6f20576f726c642122\n'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file.readlines()` returns lines *with the line separator included*.

Strip the line separator before converting from hex to bytes:

```
b = binascii.unhexlify(x.strip())
```

[`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes all leading and trailing whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines, carriage returns, etc.). Since the hex input for `unhexlify` should only consist of the letters a-z and digits anyway, that's just perfect. You could limit it to removing trailing newlines *only* with `x.rstrip('\n')`.

Note that `file.readlines()` reads the whole file into memory; in this case you could just process lines *one by one* and avoid the memory overhead. Open the outputfile *just once*:

```
with open('encoded.txt','r') as text, open('decoded.txt', 'w') as done:
    for line in text:
        decoded_line = binascii.unhexlify(line.strip())
        done.write(decoded_line + "\n")
```